# Changing background image position on hover using javascript

Tags: javascript, css

I have 10 links. I am using a separate sprite sheet for a single link which consist of active, hover and inactive link image. I want to know how can i change the background-postion from javascript. I know how to do this in css but for 10 different links i think javascript will a better option as i can use the same code for every link. Waiting for your suggestions.

Comment: Can you show us your HTML and CSS, it's hard to answer otherwise.

Comment: Are you using any JavaScript library?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

you are mistaken: this should be done in CSS, its the fastest to render, even though it takes more initial declarations.
Just make sure your CSS is optimized.

```
.links{
background:transparent url(sprite.png) 0 0;
}

#link1{
background-position: 0 0;
}
#link1:hover{
background-position: 0 -50px;
}

#link2{
background-position: 100px 0;
}
#link2:hover{
background-position: 100px -50px;
}
```

And the HTML:

```
<a class="links" id="link1" href="#">link 1</a>
<a class="links" id="link2" href="#">link 2</a>
```

If you really, really want to do it in javascript, you're looking for the style() method. [See W3Schools on style() and backgroundPosition](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_backgroundposition.asp)

Comment: typo in css `#link12` sould be `#link2`

Answer (score 3):

The best is to use css, even for multiple images.

If the sizing is the same for the sprites of the 10 links, you can make a rule that is agnostic of the image and just repositions the background image

```
a.someclass:hover{
  background-position:Xpx Ypx;
}
```

and apply the `someclass` (*or whatever you name it*) to all your links...